# Add a class depending on date

Tags: date

I have a standard link that I would like to add a class to depending on a date. Is this possible using Javascript/JQuery?? My code at the moment is simply this:

```
<div id="box1"><a href="#" class="disabled">1</a></div>
```

So if the date is actually 1st July I would like the class to change to "current" and if the date is past 1st July (2nd, 3rd, 4th etc) then the class to be "active".

I'm thinking there maybe a way to do this via Javascript or JQuery or possibly PHP. I'm not a developer so really not too sure. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

- Do your date logic

  - Remove the class:  `$("#box1 a").removeClass('disabled');`
  - Then add class:     `$("#box1 a").addClass('active');`